# Is it possible to customize the touch mode buttons in outlook (2016)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

When Touch Mode is enable in Microsoft Outlook [2016] a set of buttons appear on the right side of the reading pane. These buttons include a delete, reply, mark unread etc.

Is it possible to customize this tool bar in the same way you can add / remove buttons from the quick access tool bar?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid it is not feasible to customize the buttons in Touch Mode tool bar. You may submit the feedback via the [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/).